# Flask Button click not generating POST message

Tags: ajax, flask, jinja2

I am using flask to generate a single webpage.

The webpage has couple of text boxes and a button.On button click, I am planning to display table in the same page with the values fetched from the inputs.

```
Below is the flask code in python
===========================
    @app.route('/')
    def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


    @app.route('/ApplyFilter',methods=['POST','GET'])
    def ApplyFilter():       
        print("Hello")
        if request.method == 'POST':
            import  CompareDataset as cmp
            df3= cmp.CompareDataset()


             #conver the dataframe to the json objects
             AllRecords = json.loads(df3['both'].to_json(orient="records"))

             # count the number of records
             totalItems = df3['both']["Client"].count()
             client=request.form["client"]
             account= request.form["account"]
             auditstatus = request.form["auditstatus"]
             effectivedate=request.form["effectivedate"]
             cyclecode=request.form["cyclecode"]
             return   




     jsonify({'data':render_template('ApplyFilter.html',AllRecords=AllRecords,totalItems=totalItems)})

    return redirect('/')


snapshot of the html is as below

            <td>
                <a href=# id=applyfilter><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active">Apply Filter</button></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    {% if  AllRecords %}
    <div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-left">
    <div class="counter"><span>Total Records Found : {{ totalItems }}</span></div>
    <div   "border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; overflow-y: scroll;" >
    <table class="table" style="width: 90%; height: 100%;" >
    <thead style="color: #333; background-color: #f1f1f1">
      <tr>
        <th>Audit Status</th>
        <th>Client</th>
        <th>Effective Date</th>
        <th>Source System Code</th>
        <th>Account Number</th>
        <th>Cycle Code</th>
        <th>AuditTrailtimeStamp</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="success" >
        {% for key,value in AllRecords.iterrows() %}
        <td>{{ value["AuditStatusCode"] }}</td>
        <td>{{ value["Client"] }}</td>
        <td>{{ value["EffectiveDate"]  }}</td>
        <td>{{ value["SourceSystemCode"] }}</td>
        <td>{{ value["InternalAccountId"] }}</td>   
        <td>{{ value["CycleCode"] }} </td>
        <td>{{ value["AuditTrailtimeStamp_x"] }} </td>
    {% endfor %} 
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  </div>


    {% endif %}
    </form>


The java script tagged to button is as below

    $(function() {
    $('a#applyfilter').bind('click', function() {
    $.getJSON('/ApplyFilter', {
    client : $("client").val(),
    account : $("account").val(),
    auditstatus : $("auditstatus").val(),
    auditstatus : $("auditstatus").val(),
    effectivedate :$("effectivedate").val(),
    cyclecode : $("cyclecode").val(),
     }, function(data) {
    data = data.data;
    });
    return false;
    });
    });

On button click ApplyFilter is getting called. But it is not generating the POST message

    127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2018 17:45:40] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - Hello
    127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2018 17:45:43] "GET /ApplyFilter HTTP/1.1" 302 -
    127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2018 17:45:43] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - Hello
```

The applyfilter button is not generating the post call and hence in the route Applyfilter , the if condition is not satsifying.

Please assist and advise as to what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with this code and I'm still a bit confused by what you're trying to accomplish but I'll answer your question for now.

Your logs tell you exactly what the problem is. You want that if statement to run when you send a post request. But your logs show that you are receiving a get request and returning a 302 which indicates you have been redirected which is what is happening at the bottom of your method. So if you're sending a get request, an if statement that checks if you're using a post request isn't going to fire.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2018 17:45:43] "GET /ApplyFilter HTTP/1.1" 302 -
```

You seem to be using [getJson()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_getjson.asp) when you should be using something like the [post()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp) method.

But there are other problems such as this section won't do anything

```
jsonify({'data':render_template('ApplyFilter.html',AllRecords=AllRecords,totalItems=totalItems)})

return redirect('/')
```

For some reason you're jsonifying a call to render_template and then doing nothing with it? I can't even think what you're trying to achieve by jsonifying render_template when that function will only work within your Flask app. I may just be misunderstanding you so apologies if I am, feel free to clarify further and I'll do my best to help.

Comment: Thanks  Tim for you revert.

Comment: Thanks  Tim for you revert.  I have mad it complicate                                                .My requirement is to display the dataframe onto the sam page when the button is ciicked.Dataframe cannot be serialized and hence  used jsonify and json.loads to remove the index and convert to json.                                                 .I am reurning the jsonify only when the request is post else redirecting to the same page.   Please advise if there is an easy way to perform this